# I need to copy the contents of a text file just before the first occurance of a specified word in shell script using shell script.

Tags: linux, shell, unix, grep

I have a big text file where a particular word is repeated many times. I need the contents just above the  particular word which is firstly found from bottom in shell script,
eg: My file contains :
Tiger,Lion,Cat,Tiger,Man.

if the specified word is tiger, I need the new file which contains Tiger,Lion,Cat,Tiger

Comment: Please edit your title: should be "last" occurrence than "first" occurrence, according to your description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this One.

`sed -r 's/(,Tiger),(.*)/\1./g'`

Answer (score 1):

Lengthy, but something like

```
$ tac input | sed -n  '/Tiger/, $ p' | tac
Tiger
Lion
Cat
Tiger
```

From man page

```
   tac - concatenate and print files in reverse
```